# Updating HTML files using PHP from form input

Tags: php

Basically, I want to update static HTML files with code snippets input by users from a standard form. I understand how updating the files work, I'm just unsure as to how I go about including the code input from the form to my php file, which is shown below.

```
<?php
if($handle = opendir()) {
$search = '</body>';
replace = <<< EOF
<!-- I want to populate this with form field input.-->
EOF;
while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if(is_dir($entry)) continue; 

    $content = file_get_contents($entry); 
    $content = str_replace($search, $replace . '</body>', $content); 
    file_put_contents($entry, $content); 
}
}

echo 'done';

?>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: i dont really understand the point of this, could you be more specific of what you whant to do?

Comment: Essentially, all this is is a simple way for a friend to update a shopping cart (simplecart) someone hacked together for her without the need to directly modify source as she keeps breaking things and the original dev has disappeared. The files would be .htaccess protected. I'm a data analyst and by no means a developer. This just seemed like the most simple solution in my mind.

Comment: and what does shopping cart has to do with creating html files? I'm a litte confused :)

Comment: Simplecart is a JavaScript based shopping cart with no back-end that does not use a database, paypal api. That means no UI for updating and adding new items. They must be added by editing source. I'm trying to help a friend out by setting something up that allows her to add new items from a .htacess protected file as opposed to directly editing source and uploading new files herself.  I'm not trying to create html files, I'm trying to modify an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this a bit differently.  I suggest having a template file aside from the one being modified.  That way, you are always modifying a fresh copy instead of having to worry about what changed in the new version.

If your needs become more advanced beyond simply dropping in some markup, I might suggest using a DOM parser.

Finally, I'm sure you have a good reason for writing these static files... just remember the security implications of doing so.  You're effectively letting someone do almost anything they want to your server.

Comment: Brad, thank you for your suggestion. Essentially, all this is is a simple way for a friend to update a shopping cart (simplecart) someone hacked together for her without the need to directly modify source as she keeps breaking things and the original dev has disappeared. The files would be .htaccess protected.

Comment: @RyAnMoRgan This isn't a good method for what you want to do.  You should use a proper shopping cart with a user interface for updating product information in a database.

Comment: I am by no means a developer Brad, I'm a data analyst and I did not initially set this up. I understand it's nowhere near the best solution to the problem but it's the only thing thats within my limits. She probably generates $40 worth of sales from this store per month. It's not a big operation. I'm just trying to make it work, so that she's not calling me every time she has to modify source to add an item. :)

Comment: @RyAnMoRgan I hope you are not managing the financial part of this shopping cart yourself as well.  There are liabilities and regulation compliance requirements if you do.  There are many off-the-shelf shopping carts you can certainly install, if you are able to write the code you show in your answer.

Comment: Absolutely not. I'm just trying to help the girl out. It appears now that I cant, all I can do is suggest she contact a developer for an e-commerce solution. I absolutely could set her up an "off-the-shelf" system but I just don't have time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I agreed it was in no way the best solution to the specific problem, for anyone that may find this useful in the future I used file_get and str_replace to achieve desired results. The code below will allow you to search a file for a specific term and replace with whatever you want based on form input.

```
<?php
//These are the variables the html file will post to the script.
$filename = $_POST['myFile'];;
$tofind = $_POST['myFind'];;
$toreplace = $_POST['myReplace'];;


$file = file_get_contents($filename);

$end = str_replace($tofind, $toreplace, $file);


 $fp = fopen($filename, "w"); //Open the filename and set the mode to Write
 if(fwrite($fp, $end)) ; //Write the New data to the opened file
 fclose($fp); //Close the File



echo(" File name is $filename ... Finding $tofind .... Replacing with $toreplace .....           Done !");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Though it's a horrible solution, mixed with your code this will do

```
$replace = array_key_exists('input',$_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST['input'] : ''; 
//$replace = sanitize($replace); // there's so much bad with this string
//do the needfull
?>
<form method='GET' action='#'>
   <input type='text' name='input' />
   <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you getting this "sanitize" function?  Where are you writing the output?  You should provide explanations in your answers, especially for those just getting started.

Comment: sanitize, is something what one should write by himself, im just saying there's all kind's of horror could happen if you just input something carelessly

Comment: The requirement is that HTML is present.  Unfortunately, sanitizing is not possible in this situation.  This is for building some admin utility, not working with general input from untrusted users.  Agreed though, it is a horrible solution all around.

Comment: Thanks Benedictus for taking the time to post also.